# Handling Token From URI AngularJS and Web API

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, oauth, token

I know there are tons of examples for Token authentication and OAUTH, but I haven't been able to make sense of any for my needs.

I have created an AngularJS/Web API application that displays data from a database in some forms using Web API calls. Our company has an authentication portal, that once you have logged in, if you have access to the application, it will redirect to the application URL with additional data such as token, login_id, etc. I don't plan to have a registration or login page in my application at all. I simply want to use the redirect URL to authenticate the user with the token provided. I will need to make some additional calls to see about additional rights.

The user is redirected to my URL with the additional parameters in this form:

> https://myserver.com/?data=AOSTOKEN_1_5:XXXXXXXXX&logonId=XXXXX&badAttempts=0&passwordExpireMs=1517223840000&version=1&changePassword=false&country=US&css=&js=&language=en&limited=null&x=31&y=4&staticId=123456789&faceStaticId=null

My intuition is that I need to make a route (I'm using MVC System.Web.Routing to handle route management) for my Web API to handle this data, but I don't know how that will work with the AngularJS view. The closest example I can find is from [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1223/secure-aspnet-web-api-using-tokens-owin-angularjs), but I won't be using a database or anything. I know this is a vague question, but any help will be great!

Comment: Which angular router are you using? Can you store sessions on server in your app?

Comment: @charlietfl That's a very good point I didn't make. I'm actually stuck with System.Web.Routing that is part of MVC. I'll update my question to reflect that. I can do whatever I want on this server, but not sure how/what you mean by storing them.

Comment: Just not sure if you need to validate all requests made from angular app. Should be easy to use MVC to make sure user is logged in before displaying angular app (and redirect to login as needed). Really not sure where your complications are specifically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do some quasi authentication using the HomeController.cs file of my MVC application. I can parse the query string data in the main method (or any of the other view's methods) by adding some parameters.

For this instance, I modified my Index method to the following:

```
public ActionResult Index(string data, string logonID, string badAttempts, string passwordExpireMs, string staticId, string faceStaticId, string version)
{
     //Handle null data, validate token data, and redirect if unauthorized.
}
```